# POST method python - check status code

Tags: python, json

I need help with the task.
I have an automatic test that fills my form and adds an element after pressing the Save button. In my case, it adds the product to the store database.
I have to check if I get the code 200 after pressing the SAVE button. POST has been sent well.

My code:

```
    def methodPOST(auth, url, code, data):

         headers = {'charset': 'utf-8', 'Authorization': auth}
         response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

      if not response.status_code == code:
         file = open("path", 'a')
         file.write(response.request.method)
         file.write("\n Code: " + str(response.status_code) + "\n 
           expected: " +str(code)+"\n")
         file.write(str(response.reason) + "\n")
         file.close()
```

I have a problem because I send the same again and then I check the code. I get the code 409[not 200], because I'm trying to add the same thing again. I can not check POST and its STATUS CODE when I press the SAVE button.
How can I change my code?

Thank you for help!

Comment: why don't you add a random number to your data so so every time that you submit the request you will have different data and it will always been add to the DB?

Comment: Yes, I know this solution, but I have to do it as I wrote. Such a task.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do that? Is it not to be done?
Check the code after clicking Submit. which runs the POST method. without re-sending POST to the same address?

Answer (score 0):

409 means CONFLICT at Client side.

https://httpstatuses.com/409

You should use PUT method instead of POST as you are trying to send the same information.

refer here :- https://www.keycdn.com/support/put-vs-post/

Comment: Yes, but I have to check the correctness of POST sending

Comment: @Tom1425 i dont think POST can handle repeated posting of same information, can you tell me why is this needed  :)

Comment: so why don't you add a new statement elif not response.status_code == "409:" and in this case you take care of this case and write in the document that the data haven't been saved because duplicate?

Comment: Because I can't send second times this, it's my exercises :) , I need check with code 200. I don't know why the teacher gave such a task, but I need make this with this solution - status code == 200 and i can't send POST